# site name vs host name on iis 7 - adding a new site

Tags: iis-7, hostname

I am adding a new site in the IIS7. It asked me to enter site name and host name. I didn't get the difference. Could you please explain about it. 
thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The site name is a descriptive name which will appear in the IIS management interface. This name can be anything that allows you to determine at a glance what the site is.

The host name is the name that you will use in the host portion of the URL, i.e. http://**thisisthehostname.example.com**/bla/bla/, the bold part is the host name. The host name is functional because the web server (IIS) can have multiple sites defined, and will use the host name in the URL to decide which site to use for an incoming HTTP request.